# Microsoft Exchange delegating access to calendar but not mailbox

Tags: calendar, outlook, microsoft-exchange

Goodafternoon,

Recently I joined an organization which uses some old software. In this case Exchange 2010 and Microsoft Outlook 2010. We use an external party which hosts the exchange server. Now we have a problem and they are saying there is no solution but only grant access to a mailbox to see and have edit permissions on calendars of colleagues.

I have been searching the web to find a solution to delegate someone with read/write access to calendar functionality only. I do not want to use "Add-MailboxPermission". I am searching for a solution which removes a lot of custom work.

Situation: User is teamlead, 40 colleagues have an own calendar which has to be filled by teamlead now and then. In the current case the User needs to add the calendar (shared) on which the owner of the calendar needs to grant permission the User is the owner of the calendar.

The ideal situation is an option "Add-CalendarPermission" in Microsoft Exchange in which we can tell exchange "User" needs "Owner access" to the calendar of users x1, x2, etcetera.

I know in the IT world nothing is impossible and for everything a solution IS possible. Does someone here know a solution/workaround to automate this action?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

While I was typing and continued my investigation I have found what I need I suppose. I am going to try the following: https://www.itsmdaily.com/how-to-set-exchange-calendar-permissions-from-the-powershell/

I think I can achieve what I want with this. If someone has a better solution and/or idea please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

What about this in PowerShell?

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission John.Smith:\Calendar" -User jane.smith -AccessRights Editor
```